# Mean.io - Prerequisite not installed: Git

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, mean.io

In the process of setting up MEAN Stack,
I set up

1. Node.js  -  MongoDB running on 27017 - bower - grunt

After installing mean module on node 0.10.28, I can not pass through the command "mean init myApp".

1. npm install -g meanio@latest
2. mean init myApp
3. "Prerequisite not installed: git".

Regards Jason

Comment: So install git. npm does not install external packages, so just install git as is required by your OS installation procedure. Also try not to `npm install -g` which means **global** unless you absolutely need to.

Comment: Just in case you don't know, Git is a source control (sometimes called version control) software. It has nothing to do with node. Just install git like how you would install firefox or world of warcraft. I'm assuming you haven't heard of git because I can't imagine anyone who knows what git is asking this question. Google "git" for more info

Comment: I have git installed on my work computer and I use it daily . I do not have it installed on my home computer but I get the error in both places. another other ideas to try ? regards Jason

Comment: Hello, I am having this issue as well. As the original author suggested I have GIT installed on my machine and use it regularly (with SourceTree GUI) but am no expert. I get the same issue suggested above when i try to init a new mean.io project. Any suggestions on how to re-word the question so that it can be opened again?

Comment: I was able to solve it by reinstalling the git - http://git-scm.com/

Comment: just in case anyone else having the same problem, if you just installed git try closing and reopening the cmd window(win7 in my case), that fixed it for me

Comment: Also, putting the Git bin directory in WIndows Environment variable path will do the trick for you. Just remember to close and reopen a fresh command prompt after that.